# setImageMatrix() didn't work

Tags: android

I write some code in `MainActivity.java`, it's doesn't work.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.activeBar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.active_bar);
    this.activeBar.invalidate();
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    int offset = (720 / 3 - 30) / 2;
    //m.setTranslate(offset, 0);
    //m.postTranslate(offset, 0);
    m.setRotate(30);

    Log.i("matrix", m.toString());
    this.activeBar.setImageMatrix(m);

}
```

I want to set the active bar above on current tab at app first start. So I need to give this pic a offset distance. When I start my demo, there is no change. Nothing happen~

Comment: I assume your code is running and you see the printout in `logcat`? Also, in the code you pasted here you don't use the `offset` variable.

Comment: @Qben yes，my code can run very well, I don't use var offset,I just want to test if the Matrix work. and the `m.toString()` can print a changed matrix, m.set*() is work! but the `setImageMatrix()` don't work~

Answer (score 0):

```
this.activeBar.invalidate();
```

invalidates the view and requests a re-draw of the view. You have to apply

```
this.activeBar.setImageMatrix(m);
```

before.

Comment: MY GOD~ IT DOESN'T WORK.(T_T)

Comment: Use m.setPostRotate(30); instead of m.setRotate

Comment: First thanks for your answer, I found the reason, it's `OnPageChangeListener`. it have a method named `OnPageScroll`, this method will be invoke at app launch,and it's arg2 is 0, so my `activeBar` be reset. code in MainActivity is right, it's only reset on `Listener`.